# Python - DataFrame - Findind data from one dataframe in another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, dataframe

2 dataframes, `DF1` is a Master Dataframe, `DF2` tells the holidays and employee has taken over the month

```
DF1=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A','B','C','D'],
   'CurrDate': ['27-Jun', '27-Jun','27-Jun', '27-Jun']})



DF2=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A','A','B','B','B','C'],'Holiday': ['27-Jun', '26-Jun','27-Jun','25-Jun','23-Jun','27-Jun']  })
```

I want to compare the `'CurrDate`' in `DF1` to '`Holiday`' in `DF2`. `DF1` to be updated to the date just before holiday. So DF1 would look like:

```
DF1=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A','B','C','D'], 'CurrDate': ['25-Jun', '26-Jun','26-Jun', '27-Jun']})
```

I am struggling to put the Dataframes in loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

datetime_format = '%d-%b'

current_date_col_name = 'curr_date'
name_col_name = 'name'
holiday_col_name = 'holiday'


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    name_col_name: ['A','B','C','D'],
    current_date_col_name: ['27-Jun', '27-Jun','27-Jun', '27-Jun'],
})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    name_col_name: ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    holiday_col_name: ['27-Jun', '26-Jun', '27-Jun', '25-Jun', '23-Jun', '27-Jun']
})


holiday_dt_col_name = 'holiday_datetime'
last_day_worked_col_name = 'last_day_worked'

# convert holiday days to datetime objects
df2[holiday_dt_col_name] = df2[holiday_col_name].apply(
    lambda dts: datetime.strptime(dts, datetime_format))

# get the day before each holiday day
df2[last_day_worked_col_name] = df2[holiday_dt_col_name] - timedelta(days=1)

# get rid of the non-minimal days.
# last_worked will be as series containing the first holiday day for each person as datetime objects
last_worked = df2.groupby(name_col_name)[last_day_worked_col_name].min()

# so now dump the datetimes to as series of strings
last_worked_strs = last_worked.apply(lambda dt: datetime.strftime(dt, datetime_format))
last_worked_strs_df = pd.DataFrame(last_worked_strs)

# join dfs on name
joined_df = df1.join(last_worked_strs_df, on=name_col_name)

# fill current date into na cells
no_holiday_rows = joined_df[last_day_worked_col_name].isna()
joined_df.loc[no_holiday_rows, last_day_worked_col_name] = joined_df.loc[no_holiday_rows, current_date_col_name]

print(joined_df)
```

```
Output:

  name curr_date last_day_worked
0    A    27-Jun          25-Jun
1    B    27-Jun          22-Jun
2    C    27-Jun          26-Jun
3    D    27-Jun          27-Jun
```

Comment: Thanks, however if you see the last_day_worked of "B" is incorrect.  It should be 26-Jun. Even though B took an off on 25th - we dont need to consider as his last date to office before the current_date of 27-Jun is 26-Jun and not 22-Jun.

Comment: Your request doesn't make clear why you do count some holiday days and don't count others.  B took off on 23-Jun and 25-Jun.  If you want to programmatically ignore some days, you need another field or another rule.

Comment: I dont want to consider all holidays, just get the latest_working_date of the employee as per their holiday calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty mock-up which properly handles holes in holiday schedules.  It doesn't deal with the edge cases of no holidays for a given user or the first recorded holiday being before the current date, but I'll leave those to you -- the basics are all here.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

datetime_format = '%d-%b'
str2dt = lambda dts: datetime.strptime(dts, datetime_format)

current_date_col_name = 'curr_date'
name_col_name = 'name'
holiday_col_name = 'holiday'

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    name_col_name: ['A','B','C','D'],
    current_date_col_name: ['27-Jun', '27-Jun','27-Jun', '27-Jun'],
})

# assuming "current_date" can vary by person
# if not, you can just ignore df1
current_dates = {
    row[name_col_name]: str2dt(row[current_date_col_name]) for ind, row in df1.iterrows()
}

holidays_df = pd.DataFrame({
    name_col_name: ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    holiday_col_name: ['27-Jun', '26-Jun', '27-Jun', '26-Jun', '25-Jun', '22-Jun', '27-Jun']
})


holiday_dt_col_name = 'holiday_datetime'
last_day_worked_col_name = 'last_day_worked'


# convert holiday days to datetime objects
holidays_df[holiday_dt_col_name] = holidays_df[holiday_col_name].apply(str2dt)

one_day = timedelta(days=1)

last_dates_worked = {}
for group_name, gdf in holidays_df.groupby(name_col_name):
    gdf_sorted = gdf.sort_values(by=holiday_dt_col_name, ascending=False)
    current_date = current_dates[group_name]

    prev_date = current_date
    last_date_worked = None
    for ind, row in gdf_sorted.iterrows():
        holiday_date = row[holiday_dt_col_name]
        time_diff = holiday_date - prev_date
        if time_diff < -one_day:
            last_date_worked = holiday_date - (time_diff + one_day)
            break
        prev_date = holiday_date

    if last_date_worked is None:
        last_date_worked = prev_date - one_day

    last_dates_worked[group_name] = last_date_worked

print("Outcome:")
for person, last_date_worked in last_dates_worked.items():
    print(f'{person}: {last_date_worked}')
print()
```

```
Outcome:
A: 1900-06-25 00:00:00
B: 1900-06-24 00:00:00
C: 1900-06-26 00:00:00
```